# how to count number of lines with jointure in Talend on Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, count, talend, join

i have 3 tables

```
supplier(id_supp, name, adress, ...)

Customer(id_cust, name, adress, ...)

Order(id_order, ref_cust, ref_supp, date_order...)
```

I want to make a job that counts the number of orders by `Supplier`, for last_week, last_two_weeks with `Talend`

```
select 
supp.name,
(
   select 
       count(*)
   from 
       order
   where
       date_order between sysdate-7 and sysdate
       nd ref_supp=id_supp
) as week_1,
(
   select 
       count(*)
   from 
       order
   where
       date_order between sysdate-14 and sysdate-7
       nd ref_supp=id_supp
) as week_2
from supplier supp
```

the resaon for what i'm doing this, is that my query took to much time

Comment: So your query works you are just wondering why it is inefficient?

Comment: i dont know how to make it with Talend :/

Answer (score 0):

You need a join between `supplier` and `order` to get supplier names. I show an inner join, but if you need ALL suppliers (even those with no orders in the `order` table) you may change it to a left outer join.

Other than that, you should only have to read the `order` table once and get all the info you need. Your query does more than one pass (read EXPLAIN PLAN for your query), which may be why it is taking too long.

NOTE: `sysdate` has a time-of-day component (and perhaps the `date_order` value does too); the way you wrote the query may or may not do exactly what you want it to do. You may have to surround `sysdate` by `trunc()`.

```
select s.name,
       count(case when o.date_order between sysdate -  7 and sysdate     then 1 end) 
                                                                                as week_1,
       count(case when o.date_order between sysdate - 14 and sysdate - 7 then 1 end) 
                                                                                as week_2
from   supplier s inner join order o
       on s.id_supp = o.ref_supp
;
```